# How do I structure my "products" table correctly with over 250,000 rows?

Tags: mysql, database-design

#### The Problem

I landed a small gig to develop an online quoting system for an electronic distributor. He has roughly a half million parts - one little screw is considered a part, one little led, etc. So there are a LOT of parts.

**One Important Note:** This is only a RFQ ( Request for Quote ). There are no prices client-side, or totals, or anything to do with money. Just collecting a list of part numbers to send to my client.

I had to collect the part data from multiple sources (vendor website, scanned paper catalog, Excel spreadsheets, CSV files, and even a few JSON files. It was exhausting, but I got it done.

### Results

Confusing at first. I had dozens of product categories, and some products had **so many** attributes that were not common to any other products. I could see this project getting very complicated, and given the fact I bid this job at $900 even, I had to simplify this somehow.

This is what I came up with, and received client approval.

**Current Columns**

```
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Datasheets               | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Image                    | varchar(85)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DigiKey_Part_Number      | varchar(46)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Manufacturer_Part_Number | varchar(47)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Manufacturer             | varchar(49)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Description              | varchar(34)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Quantity_Available       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Minimum_Quantity         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

so all products will fit this page template  (menu on bottom is error in screenshot):

[image: Product View]

**Autocomplete Off The Table?**

Early on in the design, I implemented a nice autocomplete feature:

[image: Autocomplete]

> BUT .. given the number of products in the table, is this even
> practical anymore ???

**FINAL PRODUCT COUNT:**  ***223,347***

What changes do I need to make to PRODUCTS table so that querying the table will not take forever?

These are the only queries the app will be making ( not sure if this info will help in your solution advice )...

1. Get all products by category:
   Select * from products where category = 'semiconductors'
2. Get single product:
   Select * from products where Manufacturer_Part_Number = '12345'
3. Get product count by category

I think those three actually cover everything I need to do. Maybe a couple more, but not many.

In closing...

Is there a way to "index" this table with 223000 records where searching by one or more columns can be done efficiently?

I am very new to database design, and know I do need to index SOMETHING, but ... WHAT???

Thank you for taking the time to look at this post.

Regards,

John

Comment: Take the time to [read about indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) (covers 1 & 2). 3) generate this result periodicly as its a long query that can't be optimized..

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: I agree that you should have a primary key (i.e. a product number). The Manufacturer_Part_Number can probably not be used for this, because two different manufacturers may use the same number for one of their products. A Manufacturer_Part_Number seems to be unique only in combination with Manufacturer. (You should provide a unique constraint on the two columns.) This makes it unlikely you want to find a product by Manufacturer_Part_Number alone, you'd have to limit by Manufacturer, too, or search by a unique product number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listing the queries is mandatory to answering your question.  Thanks for including them.

```
INDEX(category)
INDEX(Manufacturer_Part_Number)
```

But I suggest your second query should include `Manufacturer`, too.  Then this would be better it:

```
INDEX(Manufacturer, Manufacturer_Part_Number)
```

Everything `NULL`?  Seems unlikely.

(I've done jobs like yours; I can't imagine bidding only $900 for all that scraping.)

What will you do when there are a thousand items in a single category or manufacturer?  A UI with a thousand-item list sucks.

For how to handle "so many attributes", I recommend http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav  (I should charge you $899 for the research that went into that document.  Just kidding.)

Don't they need other lookups, like "Flash drive", which need to match "FLASH DRV"?

223K rows -- no problem.  The `VARCHARs` seem to be too short; were they based on the data?

And the table needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: I really do appreciate the answer. I made the changes you suggested. The column sizes were changed, as well as adding a new index. I added a Primary Key to the Manufacturer part number, as they should never be duplicated. I have a full text index on the description to help with the autocomplete. Sometimes there is a delay, but all in all it runs okay. I also ran the db through a normalization utility  . Regarding the cheap price, I agree, it was a give away. It's for a fellow church member, so I was okay with it. I think I learned a lot - although with indexes its hard to see the results.